# List box not populating in windows phone MVVM app

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am pretty new to windows phone app development. I am trying to fill a list box but it's not getting populated. I have debugged and saw that View model is returning the data in OnNavigatioTo method but still list box is empty. Can somebody suggest any thing after looking at the code below:

Xaml page
`

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="list box" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ListBox x:Name="mylistbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Diet}" Margin="0,0,0,101" SelectionChanged="mylistbox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!--<Grid Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top">-->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="nameblock" Text="{Binding foodName}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="57" Width="236" FontSize="36" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
                        <!--<Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="181" Click="Button_Click"/>-->
                    <!--</Grid>-->

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtFoodName" Text="{Binding foodName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="Studentnameblock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,543,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Student name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="193" FontSize="30"/>-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="marksblock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,543,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Marks" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="134" FontSize="30"/>



    </Grid>

</Grid>`
```

Code behind

```
  public partial class DietEdit : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public DietViewModel ViewModel;
    public DietEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            ViewModel = DietViewModel.GetDefault();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel.GetAllItems();

        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't find that item: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Diet Class

```
 public class Diet : ViewModelBase
{

    private long mdietid = -1;
    public long dietID
    {
        get { return mdietid; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mdietid, value); }
    }

       private long mmealid = -1;
    public long mealID
    {
        get { return mmealid; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mmealid, value); }
    }

    private string mmealname = string.Empty;
    public string mealName
    {
        get { return mmealname; }
        set { if (SetProperty(ref mmealname, value)) IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string mfoodname = string.Empty;
    public string foodName
    {
        get { return mfoodname; }
        set { if (SetProperty(ref mfoodname, value)) IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private long mserving = 0;
    public long serving
    {
        get { return mserving; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mserving, value); }
    }

   private long mcalories = 0;
    public long calories
    {
        get { return mcalories; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mcalories, value); }
    }

    private string mcreateddate = DateTime.Today.ToString();
    public string createdDate
    {
        get { return mcreateddate; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mcreateddate, value); }
    }

    private string mupdateddate = DateTime.Today.ToString();
    public string updatedDate
    {
        get { return mupdateddate; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mupdateddate, value); }
    }

    private bool isDirty = false;
    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return isDirty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isDirty, value); }
    }
    internal Diet()
    { }

    internal Diet(long dietid, long mealid, string foodname, long serving, long calories, string createddate, string updateddate, string mealmname)
    {
        this.dietID = dietid;
        this.mealID = mealid;
        this.foodName = foodname;
        this.serving = serving;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
        this.mealName = mealmname;

        this.isDirty = false;

    }


    public bool IsNew { get { return dietID < 0; } }

}
```

Edit: ViewModel.GetAllItems() is actually returning a collection of type Diet. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: What does the method `GetAllItems()` do? You could set your view model as DataContext (`this.DataContext = ViewModel`) and look if that works. Does your view model provide a collection property called `Diet`? This is the items source according to your binding.

Comment: I have updated the question with an image. It is actually returning a collection of type Diet.

Comment: Hi, if I read it correctly, your DataContext is a list of "diet". So you could bind you listbox directly to it by using just ItemsSource="{Binding}". Hope that helps. Sascha

Comment: That worked!! I just changed the itemsource and remove the name of my list and it start working. Any reason why?

Comment: it worked because the line: `this.DataContext = ViewModel.GetAllItems();` sets your datacontext to the collection you need to bind to. Therefore, in your binding, you bind without a path since the datacontect is already a collection. If you were calling `GetAllItems` in the viewmodels constructor and assigning the results to a collection in your viewmodel, you would then need to bind to that collection property.